# getting the class name of an HTML tag using XPATH

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Suppose we have this span tag `<span class="my-FAV_numberis49"></span>` enclosed in a complicated document like this:

```
<div id="box_content">
    <div class="heading">
        Description
    </div>
    Really cool description about something really cool.
    <br>

    <div class="more_detail">

    </div>
    <div class="more_detail">
        <span class="date">Today's Date is</span>June 06 2014
    </div>
    <span class="my-FAV_numberis49"></span>
</div>
```

How can I save the name of the `span` class only(i.e. "`my-FAV_numberis49`") Let us assume that the format of the document will be unchanged, but the `span` class name can change to something like "`my-FAV_numberis7`". Is there a way to do this?

I hope my question is clear. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You need to discover an invariant aspect of your document. Is the *span* you want always the *last* one in that `div`? Is it the *only* one? Is it the first one after the div with the class *heading*? Or is there an invariant part in the string? Such as `my-FAV_numberis` - does it never change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This XPath expression will select *all* the `span` elements that are *children* of the `div` with an ID of `box_content` that have a class attribute which *contains* the string `my-FAV_numberis`.

```
//div[@id='box_content']/span[contains(@class, 'my-FAV_numberis')]
```

It will match `my-FAV_numberis49`, `my-FAV_numberis7` and *any* string that contains `my-FAV_numberis`, including `other-class my-FAV_numberis99` and `this-56-my-FAV_numberisnothere`.

If there is more than one `span` that matches in this context, a *node-set* will be selected. You can avoid that adding more restrictions or a positional predicate.

If the `span` is the *last* `span` *child element* in that context you can use:

```
//div[@id='box_content']/span[last()]
```

This is based on the example you provided. If the `span` element is not always a *child* of `div` and may sometimes be inside another element, then you can use the *descendant* axis:

```
//div[@id='box_content']//span[last()]
```

which will select the *last* `span` that occurs inside the `div`, in any level.

**EDIT**: to extract the *class* name from the `span` element you can use:

```
//div[@id='box_content']//span[last()]/@class
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I was asking for, but thank you for your response. The XPATH expression you've given works great for extracting content inside the <span></span> but I actually want to get a hold of the span class name only. 

For example, you know how "name(path/to/node)" gives you the name of the node you are looking for? This is kind-of what I wanted. This name() function doesn't work for my case though because I want to figure out the class name (my-FAV_numberis49) and not only the name of the node. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Do you want the full string? You just need to add one more step to the path: `//div[@id='box_content']//span[last()]/@class`

Comment: From there, you can extract the *number* if you wish, since you know the invariant part of the string: `substring-after(//div[@id='box_content']//span[last()]/@class, 'my-FAV_numberis')` will return `49` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
//span[starts-with(@class, 'my-FAV_numberis')]/@class
```

it says look for a `span` tag with an attribute `class` that starts-with `my-FAV_numberis` and output its class attribute contents.

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

the first answers is userful

```
//div[@id='box_content']/span[contains(@class, 'my-FAV_numberis')]
exact the class name try //span[starts-with(@class, 'my-FAV_numberis')]/@class
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please say what answere is the "first", because the order can change.