# Get values in array from XPATH in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath

How to get iterated value of an object returned from XPATH request.

I have this HTML template:

```
<div class="item">
<span class="light">Date</span>
<a class="link" href="">2018</a>
(4pop)
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">From</span>
<span>
<a class="link" href="" title="Bob" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Bob</span></a>,
</span>
<span>
<a class="link" href="" title="Peter" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Peter</span></a>
</span>
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">For</span>
<a class="link" href="">Bak</a>,
<a class="link" href="">Cam</a>,
<a class="link" href="">Oli</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">Nat</span>
<a class="link" href="">Cool</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLContent,'text/html');
var infos = doc.evaluate('//div[@class="item"]/span[1]', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var nodes = [];
for(var node = infos.iterateNext(); node; node = infos.iterateNext()) {
    nodes.push(node);
    console.log(node.textContent);

    // Until here, all things works well ! Except the code from here:
    var nodde = node.nextElementSibling.attributes;

    nodde.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

My goal is to get the respective value for each categorie, for example:

```
Date = 2018, (4pop)
From = Bob, Peter
For = Bak, Cam, Oli
Nat = Cool
```

I tried to iterate: `node.nextElementSibling.attributes` but without any success !

What i have tried:

```
var nodde = node.nextElementSibling.attributes;
nodde.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

You can check it on the Javascript code, but unfortunatelly This will give null result.

Is there a way to get the expected result please ?

Comment: What is that last trailing `</div> ` hanging out there?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss You have the template as it is in the post.

Comment: My point is it appears to be an unmatched close of a div (no open pair for it)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047290/getting-the-class-name-of-an-html-tag-using-xpath

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's not needed, since `//div[@class="item"]/span[1]` will get the wanted target, but  how to `foreach` respective values of each array key ... I get the keys without problem (Date, From etc.), but the respective values is a problem, but i know they are inside: `node.nextElementSibling.attributes`, my only one is how to get them.

Comment: @zod Thank's for the link but it's not the same problem i am facing, please read again my problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Once you get an item you can iterate through `childNodes` which include tags and texts.

```
var items = document.evaluate('//div[@class="item"]', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
while (item = items.iterateNext()) {
    var values = [];
    var nodes = item.childNodes;
    for (var i = 2; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var value = nodes[i].textContent.trim().replace(',', '');
        if (value.length) values.push(value);
    }
    console.log(item.getElementsByClassName('light')[0].innerText + " = " + values.join(', '));
}
```

Prints:

```
Date = 2018, (4pop)
From = Bob, Peter
For = Bak, Cam, Oli
Nat = Cool
```

Comment: Yep, somebody in W3C standards body screwed up. Such as common case and they failed to see it so we all need to write a long code to do what should have been a single call like Array.from(xpathResult)... :-(